# How can I find the frame.origin x and y coordinates of a button in swift if autolayout and constraints are being used?

Tags: swift, autolayout

I am using autolayout with Swift and trying to write some code to add a button directly above the button the user presses. However, since I am using autolayout and all my buttons have been created programatically to adjust their size according to the screen size and orientation, the code I am using simply returns their original values.

Just to be clear, "button" is what the user is pressing and I am trying to add button2 to the view to appear directly above "button."

Currently button2 is appearing at 20, 20 which where button's original values before constraints and autolayout was programmatically applied.

My code is:

```
    let button = sender as UIButton

    // Tried this but does not work: self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    // Also this but this also does not work: button.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()

    let button2 = UIButton.buttonWithType(.System) as UIButton
    button2.frame = CGRectMake(button.frame.origin.x, button.frame.origin.y - button.frame.height, button.frame.width, button.frame.height)
    button2.sizeToFit()
    button2.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)
    button2.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    button2.setTitle(button.titleLabel?.text, forState: .Normal)
    button2.setTitleColor(UIColor.darkGrayColor(), forState: .Normal)
    self.view.addSubview(button2)
```

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use frames

```
let button2 = UIButton.buttonWithType(.System) as UIButton
button2.sizeToFit()
```

Skip CGRectMake, it will not work with autoLayout,
set the constraints instead

```
 button2.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
 self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
        item:button1, attribute: .Bottom,
        relatedBy:.Equal, toItem:button2,
        attribute:.Top, multiplier:1, constant:0))
```